# Laravel JetStream get user avatar

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am sure it is because Ive been staring at this for hours off and on that I am missing something silly. I am trying to pull the avatar of the username in question. The `:alt="user.name"` is working just fine but the avatar isn't.

I am using Laravel with Jetstream to make this work. I have it working in other places but not here. What am I doing wrong?

```
                <td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap">
                  <div class="flex items-center">
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                      <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" :src="user.profile_photo_url" :alt="user.name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-4">
                      <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        {{ user.name }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-100">
                        User Location
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
```

and script info

```
<script>
import {DotsVerticalIcon, BanIcon, AtSymbolIcon, UserAddIcon, HashtagIcon, UserCircleIcon, ExclamationIcon, ShieldCheckIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/outline';
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuItems } from '@headlessui/vue';
import UserProfileSlideout from './UserProfileSlideout.vue';

export default {
    components: {
      DotsVerticalIcon,
      Menu,
      MenuButton,
      MenuItem,
      MenuItems,
      BanIcon, 
      AtSymbolIcon, 
      UserAddIcon, 
      HashtagIcon,
      UserCircleIcon,
      ExclamationIcon,
      ShieldCheckIcon,
      UserProfileSlideout,
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
          showUserProfileSlideout: false,
        }
    },
    name: 'UserListItem',
    props: ['user'],
    methods: {
      showUserProfile() {
            this.showUserProfileSlideout = !this.showUserProfileSlideout;
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you enable profile photos in Jetstream?

Comment: Yes I did. It is working in other components

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enable profilePhotos

in the jetstream config

```
    'features' => [
        // Features::termsAndPrivacyPolicy(),
         Features::profilePhotos(), // <-------- this
        // Features::api(),
        // Features::teams(['invitations' => true]),
        Features::accountDeletion(),
    ],
```

also, make sure you link your storage

using this command :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: I’ve done both of those things. This is a code issue not feature enable issue

Comment: try to change the name of the prop it may be because there is already a prop with the same name of the authenticated user